# Writing a contextmanager that patches an object

Tags: python, mocking, contextmanager

In my Python 3 test code, I have a lot of these statements:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

user = User(...)
with patch.object(MyAuthenticationClass, 'authenticate', return_value=(user, 'token'):
    # do something
```

Now I want to write this as:

```
with request_user(user):
    # do something
```

How would I write a method `request_user` as context manager such that it patches the authentication in this way, and removes the patch after the `with` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a simple wrapper like this:

```
def request_user(user):
    return patch.object(MyAuthenticationClass, 'authenticate', return_value=(user, 'token')
```

And use it:

```
with request_user(user):
    # ...
```

Comment: Without annotating it as `@contextmanager`, this does not work. The error you get: `AttributeError: __enter__`

Comment: Good, you put the decorator on it?

Comment: Never mind, I missed the `return` in the implementation. It works, thanks!