# Django disable low level caching with context manager

Tags: django, django-cache

One of my methods in a project I'm working on looks like this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from app import models

def _get_active_children(parent_id, timestamp):
    children = cache.get(f"active_seasons_{parent_id}")
    if children is None:
        children = models.Children.objects.filter(parent_id=parent_id).active(
            dt=timestamp
        )
        cache.set(
            f"active_children_{parent_id}",
            children,
            60 * 10,
        )
    return children
```

The issue is I don't want caching to occur when this method is being called via the command line (it's inside a task). So I'm wondering if there's a way to disable caching of this form?

Ideally I want to use a context manager so that any cache calls inside the context are ignored (or pushed to a DummyCache/LocalMem cache which wouldn't effect my main Redis cache).

I've considered pasisng `skip_cache=True` through the methods, but this is pretty brittle and I'm sure there's a more elegant solution. Additionally, I've tried using `mock.patch` but I'm not sure this works outside of test classes.

My ideal solution would look something like:

```
def task():
    ...
    _get_active_children(parent_id, timestamp):

with no_cache:
    task()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution (but I think there's a better one out there):

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from django.core.cache.backends.dummy import DummyCache
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string


def no_cache(module_str, cache_object_str='cache'):
    """ example usage: with no_cache('app.tasks', 'cache'): """
    module_ = import_string(module_str)
    return patch.object(module_, cache_object_str, DummyCache('mock', {}))
```

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299862/1695437).